# How to change the Select options of multiple Selects but keep the currently selected Options selected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to keep a destination Option selected if it's already selected. If the user chooses a new client, each Select needs to change destination Options (there are often dozens of destinations per client), but keep the currently selected one if it's already in the list.

I've tried getting `$.each()` of the Selects, emptying them, and then `$.append()`ing them with the list of destinations, but it's only changing the second of three selects.

```
$('#client_id').on('change', function () { // Client is selected, load branch destinations

    // AJAX server-side script with the client id to fetch client branches
    $.post('/directtransit/getbranchlist', {'id': id}, function (data) {

        // Change all of the line items' destination options based on client branches
        $('select[id^="destination"]').each(function(){

            var currentDestination = $(this).val(); // Get items currently selected destination
            $(this).empty().append('<option></option>');
            $.each(branches, function (k, v) { // Populate select options for each of the line items

                var option = '<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>';
                // If the currently selected location is in the new option list...
                // ... keep it selected
                if (v.id === currentDestination) { 
                    option = '<option value="' + v.id + '" selected>' + v.name + '</option>'; 
                }
                $(this).append(option);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Shouldn't it be changing all of them?

Comment: `$.each(branches,` what's `branches`? and where do you use `data`? And what's the purpose of the first `$(this).empty().append('<option></option>');` ?

Comment: Also, where did that `id` (in `{'id': id}`) come from?

Comment: I also don't understand why you place the exact same options into multiple select elements... What's the purpose? Are you sure `select` is the right element to use? If I'm guessing right, simple checkboxes with several destinations would suffice instead of allowing a user to select the exact same option values in different selects... makes absolutely no sense... What are you building?

Comment: `branches` are each of the bank client's branch locations. There are several users that need to be able to verify (and therefore change) all of the line items to have a correct destination if they are inputted incorrectly. From order to pickup to verify to delivery, that line item could be going to any of the client's destinations.`select` is the only option because some clients have a few `branches` and some have dozens. The pickup bag could be going to any of the client `branches`.

Comment: Sorry, I added comments to hopefully clarify the script workflow a little.